# Inductive Proof that a recurrence isn't O(n) by showing it is Omega(nlogn)

Tags: math, big-o, time-complexity, proof, induction

Note: This is related to homework.

I am attempting to show that `T(n/3) + T(2n/3) + n >= cn , for all c > 0`.

When I attempted this, the base case failed `(T(1) = 1 >= cn, for all c > 0`, is not true). So to work around this, I thought to show that the problem has a lower bound which is higher than `O(n)`. Does this constitute a correct proof?

Comment: Is there a requirement in the problem that n start at 1? Since Big-O notation is really concerned with finding the limit, where it starts isn't usually too big of a deal.

Comment: Well, this is related to the "median of medians" problem. I suppose it doesn't say that it has to start at one, but it seems most logical to me that the base case should be an array of size one.

Comment: It might seem logical for it to start with an array of size one, but that doesn't mean it needs to for Big-O analysis. Since an array of size one is a very uninteresting case, skipping it in order to reveal the pattern for the rest of the cases is very useful (and accurate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a hint, try adding in more terms. Suppose that your function satisfies

> T(n) ≥ k<sub>1</sub>n log n + k<sub>2</sub>n + k<sub>3</sub>

Now, when you plug in n = 1, the right-hand side can be made nonzero by setting k<sub>2</sub> and k<sub>3</sub> appropriately. This sort of technique is common for using induction to upper-bound and lower-bound functions and works because those lower-order terms are irrelevant for big-O notation and handle the smaller cases gracefully.

Comment: So, if do this I presume I could say something along the lines of "T(1) = k >= cn, for all k >= c > 0" and then show "T(n/3) + T(2n/3) + kn >= cn" as I originally attempted. I still wonder: does showing that a function has a lower bound of Omega(nlogn) prove that it is not O(n)?

Comment: No, that's not what you'd do. Instead, you'd prove inductively that T(1) >= k2 + k3 for some choices of k2 and k3, then prove that T(n/3) + T(2n/3) + n >= k1 n log n + k2 n + k3 under the inductive hypothesis that T(n/3) = k1 (n/3) log(n/3) + k2 (n/3) + k3 and T(2n/3) = k1 (2n/3) log (2n/3) + k2 (2n/3) + k3. As you do so, you'll discover that there are some constants k1, k2, and k3 that make this work, but you'll have to be careful as you go. Also, yes, your original idea of proving that the function is Omega(n log n) does prove that it's not O(n); the difference is including low-order terms.